# NormalDist function in Python 3.8.1 is not working?

Tags: python

I have imported the statistics module and I am trying to call for NormalDist() function in Python 3.8.1. but for some reason this message pops up:

> NameError: name 'NormalDist' is not defined

Does anybody know how to help to resolve this?

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since statistics.NormalDist is new to python 3.8.

You cannot import it with older Python version, so the first thing you have to ensure your Python version.

**Try:**

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

**You should have output:**

```
'3.8.0 (default, Nov 14 2019, 22:29:45) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
```

Or higher version

**Next, try to import the statistics**

```
import statistics
print('NormalDist' in dir(statistics))
```

If it's returned `True`, you can use it like:

```
temperature_february = statistics.NormalDist(5, 2.5)
```